# What's the difference between a keystore and a private key in the context of application signing?

Tags: code-signing, software-distribution

What's the difference between a keystore and a private key in the context of application signing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Keystore is the container format for storing keys and certificates.
- Key is just a cryptographic information of some kind.